# all n-tiples $\{a_m\}_1^n \subset\{0,1,2,...,9\} $ such that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (a_k10^k - a_k! )=0$

Tags: summation, factorial

For arbitrary large $n \in \mathbb N$ I'm looking find all n-tiples $\{a_m\}_1^n \subset\{0,1,2,...,9\} $ such that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (a_k10^k - a_k! )=0$$

Just a hint

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Trivial hint: for $n>10$, $a_n=0$.